# Mocking kernel release on ChefSpec

Tags: ruby, linux-kernel, chef-infra, chefspec

I am trying to test that `linux-image-extra-#{node['kernel']['release']}` will be installed by my cookbook and I'm trying to mock up `#{node['kernel']['release']` using Fauxhai. So far I have;

```
    describe 'my-cookbook::recipe' do
      let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(platform: 'ubuntu', version: '14.04').converge(described_recipe) }   

      before do
            Fauxhai.mock(platform: 'ubuntu', version: '14.04') do |node|
              node['kernel']['release'] = '3.13.0-66'
            end
          end

        it 'installs linux extra image package do'
            expect(chef_run).to install_package("linux-image-extra-#{node['kernel']['release']}-generic")
        end
    end
```

Unfortunately It isn't picking up the attribute and is producing an error that shows this;

> Failure/Error: expect(chef_run).to
>   install_package("linux-image-extra-#{node['kernel']['release']}-generic")

Answer (score 0):

The way you set platform data from Fauxhai with ChefSpec is to pass a `platform` and `version` option to the Solo/ServerRunner constructor.

```
let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(platform: 'ubuntu', version: '14.04').converge(described_recipe) }
```

More to the point, you are using `==` when you mean `=`. Fix all of the above. Also you need to specify a level when setting a node attribute. But really just use the Fauxhai data for now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have that already in my test; sorry I should have included that in my question. I'll update it now.